# Wordpress hook before inserting post into database

Tags: customization, hooks

I need to do check the inserted post for certain keywords and perform some functions depending on the keywords found.

is there a wordpress hook that executes "just before the post is inserted into the database" ? Or will i have to modify wordpress core ?

Also, i will need to prevent the post from being inserted into the database if some keywords are found. is this something that can be done with a hook ? Or will a core modification be needed ?

Answer (score 5):

Available actions:

1. **pre_post_update** - Runs just before a post or page is updated.
2. **publish_post** - Runs when a post is published, or if it is edited and its status is "published".
3. **save_post** - Runs whenever a post or page is created or updated, which could be from an import, post/page edit form, xmlrpc, or post by email.
4. **wp_insert_post** - Same as save_post, runs immediately afterwards.

More info: [Plugin API/Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Post.2C_Page.2C_Attachment.2C_and_Category_Actions)

Usage:

```
<?php
add_action('action_name', 'callback_name');
```

Comment: None of these happen before the post is inserted into the database

Comment: The first one (`pre_post_update`) fires immediately before an existing post is updated (documented at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_post_update/).

Answer (score 2):

The hook is save_post:

`add_action('save_post', 'dosomething'), 10, 2);`

Comment: The hook fires *after* the post is saved (see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/). Question was about *before* the post is saved.

Answer (score 2):

the hook is `wp_insert_post_data`

which as two parameters ($data, $postarr) and its a filter hook that fires before inserting the post into the database so:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','callback_function');
```

as for `save_post` hook it happens after inserting the post to database.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can i stop the post from being saved in the database using this hook ? How ?