# What hook do you use to update a post?

Tags: posts, plugin-development

For plugin development if I intend to update a post outside of the query and after so many days based on a category what is the appropriate hook to use?

Through research from the query "wp modify post hook" I get first result of [Plugin API/Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) with a list of actions run during a request but I'm stuck on which to use:

- [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) : *This hook is called after the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is run* I only intend to update the categories and the loop will never be called so is this the best approach?
- edit_post : *Fires once an existing post has been updated.*  Not much listed but I'm looking for the posts that fit the above parameters and this states after it's been updated.

Through SE sites I see:

- [How can I edit post data before it is saved?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35931/how-can-i-edit-post-data-before-it-is-saved) but that seems to mention before the initial post creation I'm looking to modify after a given time.
- [Wordpress hook before inserting post into database](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11993/wordpress-hook-before-inserting-post-into-database) is before the post initial creation.
- [Wordpress post save/edit post hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370897/wordpress-post-save-edit-post-hook) shows after the post has been saved.

So which hook should I use to manipulate a post outside of the query based on if a post has a category?

Comment: How do you plan to update the post? I've read your question twice and don't know when or where you will update it.

Comment: It's related to this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269529/manipulate-post-category-after-time) that I'm trying to understand where I'm manipulating but I keep getting overwhelmed in the documentation.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ you can simply use wp_update_post() function instead of hooks. Refer [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) site for wp_update_post details.

Comment: Then I guess I'm misunderstanding my issue in my other question.  I thought my issue was with the hook since I get an error when I go look at any post I've tried to modify.